# Adding bibliography after appendix in Latex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, appendices

I'm new to `LaTeX` and was working on my thesis. Indexing is not working properly, I tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked.
The major challenge is that I'm not getting the bibliography in the index after all. All the references, bibliography and glossary are in a different folder named References.
Moreover, while clicking on the index (for list of tables, figures) it is taking me to the title page (currently both pages are empty, could that be an issue?).

I have the following format of the document.

```
 1. TOC
 2. tables list
 3. fig list
 4. intro
 5. chap2
 6. Appendix
 7. Glossary
 8. bibliography
```

Below is the code of appendix file

```
\appendix
\input{References/app1}
\input{References/app2}
\input{References/glossary}
```

Below is the code of main file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[section,numberedsection=autolabel, acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\makeglossaries

% Use package below to change margins 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=25mm,right=25mm]{geometry}
% text color package
\usepackage{xcolor}

% use to customize chapter headings of toc lof lot
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapternumberfont{\Large} 
\chaptertitlefont{\Large}


\addbibresource{References/references.bib}



% document begins here
\begin{document}


\input{Header/titlepage}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{Header/abstract}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\newpage


\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\newpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}

\newpage    
%CHAPTERS BEGIN
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Chapters/Intro}    

%%Appendix begining
\input{References/Appendix}
\printglossary[title=Abbreviations,type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[title=Definitions]

%printing bibliography
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no index at all in that document. Are you talking about the links in the table of contents? Do you want to add the bibliography to the table of contents? Use `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`. For the others, you may need to add `\phantomsection` before the targets to get the link anchors right. But it would really be best to post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) rather than what you have, because that code is useless to us without all the inputted files.

Comment: BTW you should load the hyperref package after all the others.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot run your code, because we don't have the files that your are `\input`ing. That means that we have to speculate a bit. First of all `\addcontentsline` can go wrong for ToCs etc. that are longer than one page. Instead of messing with `\addcontentsline` you should load `\usepackage{tocbibind}`.

Comment: If you want `biblatex`'s bibliography to be a numbered section, replace `\printbibliography` with `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]`

Comment: @frabjous and moewe Thanks for your help phantomsection and bibnumbered worked like charm. Thanks for your help and support. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @moewe Could you please help me with the usage of `\usepackage{tocbibind}` as i don't know how to use it. I have attached the link to all the file documents for your reference.
[Working Sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C8DuQB_vCNZGTHTVw67vFwWsWFtIzO0K/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please don't link to large example file collections. Make the code in your question compilable for other people (check that the file can be compiled before you submit it by running it a new, completely empty folder). There are some hints to make your code compilable at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. For your example it would probably suffice to replace all `\input{...}` by a bit of dummy content from the relevant files (or remove it completely).